# Trouble opening files in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to open a file in python. the code I am using is:

```
poem = open("C:\Users\Draco\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Conan.txt") .
```

When I use this code I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape .
```

I have checked to see if the system can find the file using the code:

```
>>> import os.path 
>>> os.path.isfile("Conan.txt")
```

This originally came back as false, but I have managed to get it to say true. However I have still been unable to get the code to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah you might want to escape the escape so to speak.
Backslashes are special characters in python and if you want them to be actual backslashes you need to escape them with a backslash

```
open("C:\\Users\\Draco\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Programming\\Conan.txt")
```

or use it raw (notice the 'r')

```
open(r"C:\Users\Draco\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Conan.txt")
```